# python == syntax error

Tags: python, operators

i am getting a syntax error with the following code via a windmill test. it looks like it does not like the ==   any thoughts on what I am doing wrong

```
counter = 0
while True:
    try:
        # some code goes here

    except:
        counter += 1
        # some code  goes here

        if counter == 3
            counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You need a colon after the if statement, and the indentation may be wrong (not easy to tell with the way you've pasted it). Also comments are preceded by a #, not //

To rephrase it correctly:

```
while True:
    try:
        # some code goes here
    except:
        counter += 1

        #some code goes here 

        if counter == 3:
            counter = 0
```

Comment: thanks. my comments do have a # and not a // not sure where you guys saw //. also my formatting is correct, was probably just the way i pasted it in. Thanks for all the input. it was just the :

Answer (score 7):

You need a colon after your if-statement.

edit: fix the formatting of your code.

I also see you're using C-style comments, which Python doesn't support. All comments in Python start with `#`.

Also, Python dellimits blocks by their indentation. Make sure you indent blocks consistently.

Comment: Also also: using a decent editor (that indents things properly and is syntax-aware) will make these problems go away.

Comment: The indentation wasn't half as bad actually until ThiefMaster reinterpreted it - I've put in an edit request to restore the formatting, as the comments were evidently not part of the code also, but commenting that bits of code were missing.